# Is there an 'Always on top' option for Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

I'd like to keep my word document always on top of all the windows. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no integrated way to do this, however there are plenty of options:

[someone asked how to keep windows on top on reddit a while ago](http://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/1l8wp9/always_on_top_programs/)